# file does not update with affect of `sed` deletion

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with getting a file updated with the effect of a sed deletion.

when i perform the following, replacing <> with appropriate filename

```
sed '$d' <filename>
```

the immediate shell output shows the last line was deleted, but upon doing

```
cat <filename>
```

it shows that this deletion hasn't been stored, why is this?

Answer (score 2):

You need the `-i` flag to change the file in place.  Without it, `sed` writes to standard output.